# Efficient list of IP addresses

Tags: c#, .net, data-structures, hashset

Working with IP4 addresses, which obviously can be stored in 32 bits. 
I need to keep track of a list of ip's, which can be a fairly long list, so would like to keep it tight as possible. I also need to have quick search of the list, so as to check if an IP is already loaded in it.

I'm currently looking at: convert the IP to a UInt32, then store the list in a HashSet.

I'm thinking there may be a better way though?

update: Hashsets of course generate hashes, which are larger than the 4 bytes of a uint. So to truly optimize this, specifically for IP4 addresses, a similar structure is needed which is optimized for 4 bytes

Comment: You could store it as a trie: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie

Comment: is there a built-in structure for this?

Comment: HashSet<uint> sounds good. What would you like to improve? Does it take too much space, too much time? Is the problem contention when the set is accessed by multiple threads?

Comment: not a built-in one, but I am sure there are generic ones floating around the web

Comment: `I need to keep track of a list of ip's, which can be a fairly long list` How many? 10K? 1M? 10M? none of them is much even for my old 32-bit PC.

Comment: it's millions, and yes the server handles it fine, but a. out of curiosity and b. as things scale larger, I could envision this becoming a problem- I don't want to consume all my system memory keeping a big list in ram.

Comment: This is a perfectly good question about optimized programming, and it gets a downvote?

Answer (score 2):

If the list is relatively static (i.e. doesn't change very often), then an array or a `List<uint>` would be a very simple way to store it. It gives you O(log n) lookup with `BinarySearch`, which is probably fast enough unless you're doing thousands of lookups per second. Inserting a new item in the list, though, is an O(n) operation. If you have to do a lot of inserts, this isn't the way to go.

A `HashSet<uint>` works well and has much faster lookup and insertion. But it will cost you. A `HashSet<uint>` will occupy about 3 times as much memory as a `List<uint>`.

### Justification of 3X memory use:

The program below allocates a `List<uint>` that contains 89,478,457 items, which used to be the maximum sized `HashSet` one could create. (Up through .NET 4.0.) It then fills that list with unique values and creates a `HashSet<uint>` from the list.

The program calculates the total allocated memory by calling `GC.GetTotalMemory(true)`, which forces a garbage collection. It then computes the amount of memory required for the list and for the hash set.

Tests run with .NET 4.5, Visual Studio 2012. Run in release mode without the debugger attached.

My output:

```
Max size = 89,478,457
Starting memory = 53,240
89,000,000
After list populated = 357,967,136
89,478,457 items in the HashSet
After HashSet populated = 1,789,622,704
List occupies 357,913,896
HashSet occupies 1,431,655,568
HashSet occupies 4.00 times the memory of List
Press Enter:
```

So I was wrong ... it's 4X for `uint`. It's 3.5X for `ulong`.

```
    private void DoStuff()
    {
        int maxSize = 89478457;
            //89000000;
        Console.WriteLine("Max size = {0:N0}", maxSize);

        var startMem = GC.GetTotalMemory(true);
        Console.WriteLine("Starting memory = {0:N0}", startMem);

        // Initialize a List<long> to hold maxSize items
        var l = new List<uint>(maxSize);

        // now add items to the list
        for (uint i = 0; i < maxSize; i++)
        {
            if ((i % 1000000) == 0)
            {
                Console.Write("\r{0:N0}", i);
            }
            l.Add(i);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();

        var memAfterListAlloc = GC.GetTotalMemory(true);
        Console.WriteLine("After list populated = {0:N0}", memAfterListAlloc);

        // Construct a HashSet from that list
        var h = new HashSet<uint>(l);

        Console.WriteLine("{0:N0} items in the HashSet", h.Count);

        var memAfterHashAlloc = GC.GetTotalMemory(true);
        Console.WriteLine("After HashSet populated = {0:N0}", memAfterHashAlloc);

        var listMem = memAfterListAlloc - startMem;
        var hashMem = memAfterHashAlloc - memAfterListAlloc;

        Console.WriteLine("List occupies {0:N0}", listMem);
        Console.WriteLine("HashSet occupies {0:N0}", hashMem);

        Console.WriteLine("HashSet occupies {0:N2} times the memory of List", (double)hashMem / listMem);

        GC.KeepAlive(l);
        GC.KeepAlive(h);

        Console.Write("Press Enter:");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: I am ready to undo my downvote if you justify `A HashSet<uint> will occupy about 3 times as much memory as a List<uint>`

Comment: @I4V: My blog post on the topic: http://blog.mischel.com/2008/05/21/more-on-net-collection-sizes/. Next to last paragraph has the 24 bytes per item statement.

Comment: excellent answer. I thought the hash would use extra memory (since the hash it creates is a bigger value than the simple 4 byte int), but I also figured the list would be about the same size. Good to know.